# Splash-Screen works in IDE but not as .jar - issue with ANT?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, splash-screen

I'm attempting to add a splash-screen to a large Java project. The application is compiled into an executable .jar file using ANT.

I am able to get the splash screen working easily from NetBeans by simply adding -splash:src/com/.../.../image.PNG to my main project's VM options. However, adding SplashScreen-Image: com/.../.../image.PNG to my manifest file fails with "SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null"

I have already opened up my .jar archive to confirm that things were set up correctly: my META-INF\MANIFEST.MF file includes the SplashScreen-Image line. I have tried moving it before or after Main-Class. My actual image.PNG is also in the archive, in the correct path location.

I compile this java project with ANT, which I can guess is the source of my problems (I was able to make a simple, "jar cmf ..." example work just fine).

I use the following to get the project elements ready for achiving:

```
   <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="Compile the source">
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <path id="lib.path.ref">
      <fileset dir="${path_to_jre}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" source="${java_ver}" target="${java_ver}"
        includeantruntime="false">
      <!--compilerarg value="-Xbootclasspath/p:${toString:lib.path.ref}" compiler="javac1.7"/-->
      <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${LibDir}">
          <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${dependant_jar}"/>
        <pathelement path="${another_dependant_jar}"/>
      </classpath>
    </javac>
    <!-- Copy the .png files -->
    <copy todir="${build}">
      <fileset dir="${src}" casesensitive="false">
        <include name="**/*.PNG"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>
```

Notice that I use a copy to move .PNG files in with .class files. My image.PNG for the Splash Screen is just in with the others. I added it to my netbeans project by simply copying it there - nothing fancy.

My achieve target is as follows:

```
   <target name="archive" depends="compile"
        description="Generate the .jar file">
    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the .jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${jarfile}" basedir="${build}">
      <!-- Merge in contents of dependency .jars -->
      <zipfileset src="${LibDir}/snakeyaml.jar"/>
      <zipfileset src="${dependant_jar}"/>
      <zipfileset src="${another_dependant_jar}"/>
      <!-- Specify main class in manifest -->
     <manifest>
        <attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="com/../../image.PNG"/>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${mainclass}"/>
         </manifest>
    </jar>
   </target>
```

So my manifest in the eventual .jar is created here, which is also where I eventually realized to add the splashscreen tag.

I am somewhat new to working with ANT, so any advice regarding how to handle this or what to look for is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, although I'm sure someone else will understand this better than I do.

I was able to run, with a splash-screen, using the Java binary in ../jre/lib/Java.exe, however I had initially been working from ../lib/Java.exe.

Looks like this is a known bug? Link here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7129420. I guess the path to the SplashScreen dll is hardcoded.

Note: Thanks to user VGR for the exhaustive help.

Comment: Interesting.  Have you tried running (no need to recompile) with a newer version of Java?  You should be able to download Java runtimes as archives, rather than installers, so you won’t have to risk altering your officially installed version.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue with Ant.  The problem is that [the -splash option takes a file name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__GUID-38DE3394-D6AD-4F49-9A68-E15D9F88C460), but [the SplashScreen-Image manifest attribute must refer to a jar entry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html).  If `com/example/brian/image.PNG` isn’t in the .jar file, it won’t be usable by SplashScreen-Image.  The purpose of a .jar file is to be act as a self-contained module or application, so it should include all of the resources it needs.

<strike>The solution is to include the image in your .jar file:</strike>

```
<jar jarfile="${jarfile}" basedir="${build}">
    <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.PNG"/>
```

**Update:** Your build file was already adding the images to the .jar with a `<copy>` task, and I failed to notice it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the fileset command in my archive target, but unfortunately I'm still seeing null from getSplashScreen().


I actually can see my image.PNG in the .jar file, if that helps. When I open the archive, I can navigate to it just fine.

Comment: Did you double-check that the SplashScreen-Image attribute value exactly matches the jar entry?

Comment: Just for additional clarification - all PNG files are copied into ${build} during the final step of the compile target. From my understanding, this means they are being correctly included in the .jar. Unfortunately, I still cannot get a splashscreen working outside of my IDE

Comment: Oh… that was there all along, wasn’t it?  Sorry, I guess I was focused on the top part of your build file.  You can disregard my fileset recommendation.  How are you examining your .jar file?  Are you doing it in the IDE, or on the command line?

Comment: I've just been opening it with 7zip. I suppose the command line would be similar. Do you mean filepath and name? I have tried as many possibilities as I can, but I have no way to debug or check. From 7zip, the filepath is **..\myjar.jar\com\dir1\dir2\image.PNG** I have **<attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="com/dir1/dir2/image.PNG"/>** in my manifest right now

Comment: This may be silly, but have you verified the validity of the image?  And are you sure it’s actually a PNG image?

Comment: Definitely worth checking! I think it is - at least, Windows thinks it is when I go through the properties. 
 
 
It also works through Netbeans (as in, I can lauch my app successfully with the right image.PNG) so I think that rules out formatting issues?

Comment: If you double-click the PNG file from within 7zip, does it display properly?

Comment: Yep! No problems there. Just to confirm though, when using a .jar I need to get a reference to the splashscreen object with `final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();` This is the first line in my main(), and it returns null. This is the right way to do this?

Comment: Just about every method in AWT and Swing needs to called from the AWT event dispatch thread, not from the main thread.  Try placing that getSplashScreen call in a private static method, and call that method from within [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeAndWait](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29).  For example, `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> processSplashScreen());`

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately no luck there either. If my manifest is correct, my java code is correct, and my jar file has the right organization/files, what else could be the problem? Aren't those pretty much the only three variables?

Comment: Try adding a sanity check in your main method, before the getSplashScreen call:  `System.out.println(MyApplication.class.getResource("/com/dir1/dir2/image.PNG"));` Note that the string needs to start with a leading slash, unlike the value of the manifest attribute.

Comment: Thank you - a sanity check of some sort was exactly what I was looking for. I see **jar:file:/E:/<path to my jar>/myjar.jar!/com/dir1/dir2/image.PNG** when running from the jar. I get a null if I spell something incorrectly

Comment: If you remove or comment out the call to SplashScreen.getSplashScreen(), do you see the splash screen with your image in it when you run?

Comment: I do from NetBeans, but I think this is because "-splash: " is handled completely differently. The .jar will just show nothing if I don't call getSplashScreen()

Comment: Well, it’s consistent with getSplashScreen() returning null, at least.  Can you verify that the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in your .jar file does in fact contain a SplashScreen-Image attribute?

Comment: Yep, I've played around with that a significant amount too. Lots of readjusting orders and spacing and newlines. No luck.  
Manifest is at myjar.jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF and contains the text `Manifest-Version: 1.0<br/>
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 20.45-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
SplashScreen-Image: com/dir1/dir2/image.PNG
Main-Class: com.dir1.dir2.mainApp`

Comment: Found a solution! Looks like its a documented bug? If you don't mind checking out my posted solution; I'm love to hear your thoughts. Thanks again for all the help